# How to make a dropdownlist disabled on change event using JQUERY?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#<%=ddlContinents.ClientID %>').change(function() { 
      var element = $(this);
      var totalLength = element.children().length; 
      if ($(this).disabled == false) { $(this).disabled = true; }
      });
});
```

What I am trying to do is fire off the change event of the `dropdownlist` and on change making this `dropdownlist` disabled. The code is firing and everything, but it does not disable the `dropdownlist`.

This portion of the code is not working:

```
if ($(this).disabled == false) { $(this).disabled = true; } });
```

Comment: Thank you everybody, I got it with this way :
        $(document).ready(function() { $('#<%=ddlContinents.ClientID %>').change(function() { var element = $(this); var totalLength = element.children().length; if ($(this).attr("disabled") == false) { $(this).attr("disabled", true); } }); });

Comment: The "proper" way is to remove the disabled attribute and set disabled to 'disabled'.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_an_element.3F

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for jQuery 1.6+ or [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for earlier versions of jQuery:

> jQuery 1.6:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=ddlContinents.ClientID %>').change(function() { 
    var element = $(this);
    var totalLength = element.children().length;

    if (!$(this).prop("disabled")) { 
      $(this).prop("disabled", true); 
    } 
  });
});
```

< jQuery 1.6:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=ddlContinents.ClientID %>').change(function() { 
    var element = $(this);
    var totalLength = element.children().length;

    if (!$(this).attr("disabled")) { 
      $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: oops, try $(this).attr("disabled") == false

Answer (score 11):

```
if (!$(this).attr("disabled")) { $(this).attr("disabled","disabled"); }
```

If you want to enable it later on, you gotta do:

```
$(this).removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old..This might help if anyone stuck with disabling dropdown on dropdown chnage function

```
  if ($(this).attr('disabled', false)) 
         { $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }
```